# Read a file a number of bytes per time in c

Tags: c, file, io, byte, fread

***I am trying to write a program on how to read a file 10 bytes per time using read, however, I do not know how to go about it. How should I modify this code to read 10bytes per time. Thanks!!!!***

```
#include <unistd.h>  
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h> 
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/time.h>


int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("I am here1\n");
    int fd, readd = 0;
    char* buf[1024];  

    printf("I am here2\n");

    fd =open("text.txt", O_RDWR);
    if (fd == -1)
    {
            perror("open failed");
            exit(1);
    }
    else
    {   
            printf("I am here3\n");

            if(("text.txt",buf, 1024)<0)
                    printf("read error\n");
        else
        {
            printf("I am here3\n");

            /*******************************
            *  I suspect this should be the place I make the modification
            *******************************/
            if(read("text.txt",buf, 1024)<0)
                    printf("read error\n");
            else
            {
                    printf("I am here4\n");
                    printf("\nN: %c",buf);
                    if(write(fd,buf,readd) != readd)
                            printf("write error\n");

            }
        }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if(("text.txt",buf, 1024)<0)`  what will this line do ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The final parameter of `read()` is the maximum size of the data you wish to read so, to try and read ten bytes at a time, you would need:

```
read (fd, buf, 10)
```

You'll notice I've also changed the *first* parameter to the file descriptor rather than the file name string.

Now, you'll probably want that in a loop since you'll want to do something with the data, and you also need to check the return value since it can give you *less* than what you asked for.

A good example for doing this would be:

```
int copyTenAtATime (char *infile, char *outfile) {
    // Buffer details (size and data).

    int sz;
    char buff[10];

    // Try open input and output.

    int ifd = open (infile, O_RDWR);
    int ofd = open (outfile, O_WRONLY|O_CREAT);

    // Do nothing unless both opened okay.

    if ((ifd >= 0) && (ofd >= 0)) {
        // Read chunk, stopping on error or end of file.

        while ((sz = read (ifd, buff, sizeof (buff))) > 0) {
            // Write chunk, flagging error if not all written.

            if (write (ofd, buff, sz) != sz) {
                sz = -1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // Finished or errored here, close files that were opened.

    if (ifd >= 0) close (ifd);
    if (ofd >= 0) close (ofd);

    // Return zero if all okay, otherwise error indicator.

    return (sz == 0) ? 0 : -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change the value in `read`,

```
read(fd,buf,10);
```

From `man` of `read`

```
ssize_t read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count);
```

> read() attempts to read up to count bytes from file descriptor fd into the buffer starting at buf.

```
 if(read("text.txt",buf, 1024)<0)// this will give you the error.
```

First argument must be an file descriptor.